# Playing video in browser: outdated browser error (Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, 16.10, video-streaming

I'm trying to watch a video in my browser (tried Firefox and Chrome). However, this video player keeps telling me my browser is outdated and the player isn't supported any more...
[image]

I don't know what I can try anymore.

- I have the most recent versions installed.
- I installed the proprietary audio & video codecs.

This is the code from the video player on the page. It seems to be a JS/html5 player.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The issue is likely to be DRM related. Nothing to do with the browser's version or codecs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Kali install (Kali is very similar to Ubuntu) I was able to fix it by enabling the flash extension (Yes I know... flash). I have not tested in Chrome but works fine in Firefox.
Link to the Ubuntu doc on this: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html